# Proof of the sentence regarding Hz to cents formula

Tags: theory, tuning, frequency

On this amazing page I have learnt that you can calculate the cents between two notes with the following formula:
c = 1200 × log2(f1/f0)

I simply wonder if there is an accessible proof of this, I can't seem to find any.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7):

It's not as much a statement in want of proof rather than a definition.  Interval widths correspond to frequency ratios so when viewed additively, they correspond to a logarithm of a frequency ratio.  A cent is defined as a 100th of a semitone of which 12 are defined to be in an octave (which is defined as a frequency ratio of 2), so we have 1200 cent per factor of 2.

Basically, this is the straightforward formulaic rendition of the definition of cent, so there is not a lot to prove.

Comment: Yep.  Another way of putting it: this is a convention, not a fact of nature.